# JQuery Delays Getting Out of Sync After Some Time - Replacing Background Images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm pretty new to all of this, but I've been able to kludge together a nice looking site, but I have a div that I want to change backgrounds on after 10 seconds or so.  I wanted the transition between images to be nicer, so I wanted the div to fade out, then the image to change, then have the div fade back in.  So, basically, I set the timeout for 10.5 seconds.  There's a .5 second fade in in the beginning, then 9 seconds of display time, then a .5 second fadeout.  Then the timeout should wait another .5 seconds, change the image, and then start all over again.

The code works at first, but after about 10 minutes, the fade in and fade out gets out of sync with the timeout function.  I'm not sure why, and it may not matter (who is going to sit and stare at my website for 30 minutes), but it's bothering me, so I thought I'd ask.  Here's the code, and thank you in advance!

```
$(function() {

var colorBackgrounds = new Array(
'url(backgrounds/home/full/20140714-_MG_0604.jpg)',
'url(backgrounds/home/full/20140714-_MG_0860.jpg)',
'url(backgrounds/home/full/20140716-IMG_1296.jpg)'
);
var colorCurrent = 0;
var greyCurrent = 0;

function nextBackground() {
$('.bodyBackground').fadeIn(500);
$('.bodyBackground').delay(9000).fadeOut(500);
$('.bodyBackground').css({
    'background':colorBackgrounds[colorCurrent = ++colorCurrent % colorBackgrounds.length],
    'background-position':'center center',
    'background-repeat':'no-repeat',
    'background-attachment':'fixed'
    });
setTimeout(nextBackground, 10500);
}

setTimeout(nextBackground, 10500);
$('.bodyBackground').fadeIn(500);
$('.bodyBackground').delay(9000).fadeOut(500)
$('.bodyBackground').css({
    'background':colorBackgrounds[0],
    'background-position':'center center',
    'background-repeat':'no-repeat',
    'background-attachment':'fixed'});
});
```

Comment: Use the callback to do the next step: `$('.bodyBackground').fadeIn(500,function() { ... })`

Comment: I get it now - excellent!  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function () {

    var colorBackgrounds = new Array(
            'url(backgrounds/home/full/20140714-_MG_0604.jpg)',
            'url(backgrounds/home/full/20140714-_MG_0860.jpg)',
            'url(backgrounds/home/full/20140716-IMG_1296.jpg)'
            );
    var colorCurrent = 0;
    var greyCurrent = 0;

    function nextBackground() {
        $('.bodyBackground').fadeOut(500, function () {
            $('.bodyBackground').css({
                'background': colorBackgrounds[colorCurrent = ++colorCurrent % colorBackgrounds.length],
                'background-position': 'center center',
                'background-repeat': 'no-repeat',
                'background-attachment': 'fixed'
            });
            $('.bodyBackground').fadeIn(500, function () {
                setTimeout(nextBackground, 9000);
            });
        });
    }

    nextBackground();

});
```

FadeIn and FadeOut are asynchronous method. It means that they are executed in parallel with the main process.

The solution here is to use Callbacks. A callback is a function that is called when an asynchronous function finished it work.

You can see that I propose you some code with others differencies! Instead of showing then hiding. It hide and show. Its simpliers to understand to me.

Comment: I ended up doing just about exactly that - thank you!

Answer (score 1):

seconding @mplungjan 
Since the "fadeOut" and "fadeIn" methods are asynchronous , you're going to get out of sequence unless you use callbacks to enforce the order you would like this performed in. Like so :

```
var colorBackgrounds = new Array(
    'url(backgrounds/home/full/20140714-_MG_0604.jpg)',
    'url(backgrounds/home/full/20140714-_MG_0860.jpg)',
    'url(backgrounds/home/full/20140716-IMG_1296.jpg)'
);

var colorCurrent = 0;
var greyCurrent = 0;

function nextBackground() {
  $('.bodyBackground').fadeIn(500, function(){
    $('.bodyBackground').delay(9000).fadeOut(500, function(){
      $('.bodyBackground').css({
        'background':colorBackgrounds[colorCurrent = ++colorCurrent % colorBackgrounds.length],
        'background-position':'center center',
        'background-repeat':'no-repeat',
        'background-attachment':'fixed'
      });
      setTimeout(nextBackground, 10500);
    });
  });  
}


nextBackground();
```

Comment: Thank you for posting the completed code - I was playing around with it, but had forgotten to add the second stage of callbacks and it was still messed up.  This makes a ton of sense!

Comment: Glad I could help :) 
it will still require some tweaks but it could get you started. I would actually recommend toggling these through css classes instead of relying on jquery.

Comment: I tried that, but there is a lot more code to this than I actually posted, including calculation of the image aspect ratio and comparing it to the browser ratio, preloading, and randomization for some pages, so it seemed easier to just go all in on the JQuery, especially since I'm pretty new to this stuff!  Thank you!